# How to correctly instantiate ISet

Tags: c#, dataset, iesi-collections

I have a parent object that has an attribute of ISet however I havent been able to instantiate the set correctly...how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the HashSet class.

Comment: I actually had to use HashedSet<>()

Comment: So it's Iesi.Collections.dll? You forgot to mention that :P